# Mono for Android - Binding Projects won't build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, xamarin.android

We are using the Facebook binding project from here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook

Trouble is, my PC won't build the project (Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010)--basically no C# classes are created (no generated *.cs files or anything).  There are also no errors reported.

My co-worker's Windows machine works just fine, and we appear to have the same versions of everything installed.  I tried reinstalling Java, the Android SDK, and Mono for Android with no luck.  Anyone else have this issue?

I also tried on my Mac, and it worked just fine.

My PC Info

- Java 6 Update 31
- Java SE Development Kit 6 Update 31
- Windows 7 64 bit
- Android SDK Tools 1.16
- Mono for Android 4.2.3
- Visual Studio 2010
- MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2
- Used Xamarin Mono for Android Installer 3.0.0.0